# How to put <input> tag into an extra div in bootstrap 4 form-inline?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Imagine the following simple form:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="direction: ltr">
            <form class="form-inline flex-fill">
              <div class="input-group input-group-lg flex-fill mx-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-center" placeholder="" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-search text-muted"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

If you insert the <input> element inside an extra <div>, it doesn't display properly. Like <div><input.../></div>

It looks like the bootstrap styles expect the input to be the immediate child of input-group. How do you solve this in bootstrap 4?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. You're applying various flex box utility classes all over your form... which is already using its own set of flex box rules. There are some classes that are mistyped as well.

Comment: I'm just trying to make a full-width form, flex classes are only there to make the form full-width.
Class mistypes have been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the need for this use-case... specifying `.form-inline` and then wanting to use a full-width `.input-group` but in a fashion outside the design pattern of that component? It's very odd but it can be done!

The heavyweights of this alteration are `.form-control` and `.w-100`.  Because you're applying `.form-inline` to the base form the behavior of all of the various form elements is going to be to take only as much width as absolutely necessary; `.w-100` tells them to take it all.

Applying `.form-control` to the wrapper `<div>` lets Bootstraps CSS know how to handle this unexpected element, but it causes some conflicts with the child `<input>` that you need to override with a few extra classes.

On `.form-control` you need to remove any padding, and on the `<input>` you need to remove well... everything basically.  You need to remove its default border (`.border-0`), add a `.rounded` class to avoid the rectangular input clipping into the `.form-control`.  You need to make it take up 100% of its parents width and height (`.w-100` and `.h-100` respectively)

And even then you're going to have a little bit of inconsistency with the `:focus` effect compared to how the `.input-group` component functions when the default pattern is honored.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-DJ25uNYET2XCl5ZF++U8eNxPWqcKohUUBUpKGlNLMchM7q4Wjg2CUpjHLaL8yYPH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="form-inline p-3">

<div class="input-group input-group-lg w-100">
  <div class="form-control p-0"><input type="text" class="border-0 rounded w-100 h-100 text-center"></div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-search text-muted"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. The use case is that I'm using an autocomplete component that generates the <input> inside a <div>, so, I'm forced to have the input tag inside an extra div. Your solution is actually working in general, but inside my markup it does not display the text input and button inline. so I added 'flex-basis:0; flex-grow:1' to the extra div and its working! I couldn't find out what causes this and how flex styles fix that.

Comment: @Rev: OMG I spent days trying to fix this silly issue. You are a life saver. You should point that out in the main question or in a separate answer. `flex-basis:0; flex-grow:` Fixed my issue!!. Thanks again.